# Can't compare two properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

Hi I have a method where I find an object  with linq

```cs
 Item c = lineCollection.items
    .Where(p => p.item
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("Product_ID")
        .GetValue(p.item) == product
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty("Product_ID")
            .GetValue(product)
    )
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

The problem is that the `p=>p.item.(...)` value is always 0 but if I call this value from a view it is 1 and it's ok. What is the cause? `Product_ID` of product object is correct but I saw I can't even call properties of `p => p.item to` a `List<PropertyInfo>`

Here is more of code:

```
 private CartLine lineCollection = new CartLine();

public void AddItem(Object product, int quantity)
{
    Item c = lineCollection.items.Where(p => p.item.GetType().GetProperty("Product_ID").GetValue(p.item) == product.GetType().GetProperty("Product_ID").GetValue(product)).FirstOrDefault();
    if(c == null)
    {
        lineCollection.items.Add(new Item { item = product, Quantity = quantity });
    }
    else
    {
        lineCollection.items
        .Where(p => p.item.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault().GetValue(p.item) == 
               product.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault().GetValue(product) && p.item.GetType() == product.GetType())
               .FirstOrDefault().Quantity += quantity;
    }
}
public CartLine Lines
{
    get { return lineCollection; }
}
```

And a code in view where i can find Product_ID property

```
 @model KomShop.Web.Models.CartViewModel
 @foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines.items)
{
     @line.item.GetType().GetProperty("Product_ID").GetValue(line.item)
}
```

Finally CartViewModel

```
 public class CartViewModel
 {
     public Cart Cart { get; set; }
     public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately with just a single line of code it's going to be quite hard to help you. It would really help if you could provide a [mcve]. If you could avoid using reflection at all, that would almost certainly make the code simpler and more robust, too.

Comment: I send more of code below

Comment: As noted, the code should all be in the question. But it's still unclear why you're using reflection at all. Do you not know the type of the product? Not even an interface it will implement?

Comment: project has many classes for different products and I want to optimize it its not good to copy "additem" void for more than 20 products. That's why i want to make it that

Comment: "project has many classes for different products" - so make them all implement the same interface that declares a `ProductId` property. "Optimizing" and "using reflection" rarely go hand-in-hand...

Comment: Okay thanks but how should I do it? One interface with ienumerable<itemclass> but what with ProductID? Or it should be an interface with interfaces inside? Sorry but I just learned the platform

Comment: No, just an interface of `IProduct` or something, with a `string Product_ID` property (or better, `ProductId`). Then you'd make sure your `lineCollection.items` (also not conventionally named...) property returned an `IEnumerable<IProduct>`